# Can "user popups" be disabled?

Tags: feature-request, user-interface

I see that the [new feature of a profile popup](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/104810) for a user of <strike>sufficient rep</strike> rep $\geq 1000$ appearing when one mouses over the user's Gravatar has been implemented. My thinking is that I am not that lazy to not visit the user's profile page if I am interested in learning more about him/her, so this popup is rather annoying.

Is there a way to add a user setting for enabling/disabling this?

Comment: Maybe you can tweak [one of the scripts](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1512) mentioned here (I don't know how, but would **love** to know)

Comment: @Theo: Oh joy, Greasemonkey. I could, but I sure wish I didn't have to... :(

Comment: `<rant>` I have nothing against that info being displayed *on request*, by clicking, or, say, by increasing the wait-time to 5 seconds. However as is, we'll soon have reached the point where there is no safe zone for your mouse pointer anymore when scrolling vertically. If only [the hate of meta tags](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/) extended to the unsolicited display of meta-info. `</rant>`

Comment: One particular annoying side effect of this is that one can no longer easily cut and paste a username because as soon as the mouse hovers near it, one gets the popup. I used to use this to copy usernames not easy to type (e.g. with accent characters)

Comment: @Bill: You can still use copy and paste _within_ the popup. But I agree that it's not as convenient as before.

Comment: @Bill: You can copy usernames if you approach the name from the right side -- the annoying pop up seems to appear only if you hover over the icon/gravatar, not the username itself.

Comment: @Shr Indeed, that workaround does the trick - although it is a bit more cumbersome than pre-popup. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They've just changed the behaviour; the popup only appears when you hover over the gravatar. I find this makes the whole thing a lot less annoying. See [How does the User Card popup work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/104810/how-does-the-user-card-popup-work/104838#104838)

Comment: That's a great development!

Comment: That's better. What's still annoying is that if I start copying a username (from right-to-left to avoid the popup) it's still difficult to avoid hitting the popup. The popup should be disabled if one is in the middle of a copy operation.

Comment: @Bill: For me it behaves exactly as you rightly propose: if I copy from right to left, the the popup doesn't appear, even if I move the mouse pointer too far to the left.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want the Gravatar in your user card to be, as Theo puts it, "hover-dangerous", here's a hackish way of making it so:

From [this meta.SO question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/104810), there is the line

> ...we support explicitly specifying your user card excerpt summary
>   using the following syntax:
>
> `<!-- summary: This is my profile, there are others like it but this
>   one is mine. -->`

What I did for my profile was to insert

`<!-- summary: &nbsp; -->`

before all the other stuff showing up in my profile (I suppose any other non-displaying character but a space would do, as plain `<!-- summary: -->` doesn't work). You can go check that nothing pops up anymore when you hover your mouse pointer over my Gravatar.

(Of course, this is a per-user thing, so still not a good solution...)

Answer (score 2):

After peering through the HTML (sigh), apparently this new bit is called `user-menu`; I suppose this straightforward modification of [Simon Brown's script](https://stackapps.com/questions/2129/hide-tag-info-popup) might work:

```
var style = document.createElement("style");
style.type = "text/css";
style.textContent = "#user-menu { visibility: hidden !important; }";
document.body.appendChild(style);
```

Any willing Guinea pigs there? (For reasons I don't want to elaborate on, Greasemonkey is giving me headaches on my box.)

Comment: P.S. (The only answer I'll be accepting is an answer pointing out a user-settable option linked to somewhere in the profile page...)

Comment: I think that if your profile is incomplete you don't get a popup.

Comment: Mine is incomplete, but there's still a popup on my Gravatar...

Comment: Cool! It works... almost. [now only the Gravatar pops up](http://i.stack.imgur.com/zeXYI.png) (I don't know how to capture my mouse pointer that was right between your eyes).

Comment: @Theo, JM: It is strange because Theo doesn't have a popup, but me and JM do. Perhaps something with the "About" text?

Comment: @Asaf: that's what I would have guessed, too, but Jeff Atwood has about-stuff but doesn't have a popup.

Comment: @Theo: And moderators can edit comments even past the five minutes limit. Those with power can enjoy a bit more... it is the law of nature. :-P

Comment: @Asaf: Right, the popup only appears if the info text is long enough. I don't know exactly what qualifies as "long enough".

Comment: @Theo: could you try appending `div.um-gravatar.style.visibility = 'hidden'` to the script?

Comment: Done; I tried inserting it in various places but no matter where I insert it, it breaks the script completely, i.e., the *entire* popup appears (also when I add a semicolon at the end of the line). By the way: did you notice the fancy shadow the hover-dangerous gravatars now have instead of a white triangle? :)

Comment: Thanks @Theo. At the very least, I now know that the element displaying the Gravatar in the popup is `div.um-gravatar`; I'm not too motivated to look into my CSS refs to see what should really be done, and I hope somebody with better scripting ability comes along to modify what I've written. Sorry for the trouble.

Comment: Thank you, it's already much better this way, I can live with that. It's also a bit counterproductive to work against the higher-ups by trying to circumvent the scripts they're just about to install. I'm sure a script will soon appear on stackapps.

Comment: Bleh, I should really be noting the SE engine versions when I complain about "features"; we're apparently now at `rev 2011.9.1.2`; so I suppose that white triangle in `2011.9.1.1` was removed...

Comment: @Asaf The requirements are that the user's "About Me" section must have at least a certain length (a few sentences is usually sufficient), and that the user have at least 1000 reputation.

Comment: @Asaf: to add to Grace's note (heh. :)), Arturo has a pop-up, so I suppose the character length required of "About Me" for a corresponding popup isn't that long...

Comment: @J.M. the next reasonable test case would be *moi*. I have only one word.

Comment: @Willie: You don't have a popup, so the minimum character length ain't that small. ;)